# Detect dynamically added elements jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a button which is added dynamically

```
    <button id="btnSubmit">Button 1</button>

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
        alert('Button 1');
        var button2 = '<button id="btn2" >Button 2</button>';
        $('#btnSubmit').after('<p></p>' + button2);
    });

    $(document).on('#btn2', 'click', function(){
        alert('Button2 clicked');
    });
  });
```

Now, when I click on #btn2 the event is not detected. How can this be fixed?

Comment: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/victor_007/ymea68rc/) like this

Comment: Even tried with .on()

Answer (score 1):

You are adding `btn2` for every click of `btnSubmit`, this will create multiple buttons with same `id` and it is not acceptible with jQuery.

Use unique `id` or `class` for every dynamic button adde, and use `.on()` to bind click event to button, see below code

HTML

```
 <button id="btnSubmit">Button 1</button>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
        alert('Button 1');
        var button2 = '<button class="btn2" >Button 2</button>';
        $('#btnSubmit').after('<p></p>' + button2);
    });

    $(document).on('click','.btn2', function(){
        alert('Button2 clicked');
    });
  });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    alert('Button 1');
    var button2 = '<button id="btn2" >Button 2</button>';
    $('#btnSubmit').after('<p></p>' + button2);
    $(document).bind('#btn2', 'click', function(){
    alert('Button2 clicked');
    });
});
});
```

try this code It will work. or you can try this as well.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $('#btnSubmit').on('click', function(){
    alert('Button 1');
    var button2 = '<button id="btn2" >Button 2</button>';
    $('#btnSubmit').after('<p></p>' + button2);
    $('#btn2').live('click', function(){
    alert('Button2 clicked');
    });
});
});
```

Comment: `live()` has been deprecated for years. It doesn't even exist in recent versions of jQuery